# Regular Voltage Spikes on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian-buster, voltage

[Running Raspian v10, Buster]

I'm using a raspberry pi zero with a waveshore ADS1256 high precision board. I'm getting regular voltage spikes 30 seconds regardless of the input.

I've disabled wifi, bluetooth, most anything I can think of. Is there a service on the rPi that runs at this interval that could be causing my noise?

[image]

Comment: You get similar if you feed 3.3V into the input?

Comment: If you want a good answer, please ask a [good question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You've not explained **where** you are taking your measurements, what you're doing, or why 10uV noise is significant. "Noise" is everywhere.

Comment: (Noted, will save that link)

I am trying to measure a voltage to a high precision. I am currently using this on my desk, the adc input is attached to a wheatstone bridge. The rPi zero is powered by USB from a laptop for now.

I'll dig in to seeing if environmental noise could be a culprit, my first thought was it's a service as the voltage spike is similar to when I send a command via putty.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to find the culprit inside the RPi, I would make sure it's not outside. Perhaps there is something in your house that runs at this interval and produces noise in the power network? Or something on your desk, right next to the Pi?

It's also not clear what exactly you are measuring. Floating ADC inputs pick up noise from lots of stuff, they can even toggle when you approach your hand.

Try running your Pi from a battery and put it away from other electronics. Make sure that you are measuring a stable voltage, e.g. ground or battery voltage via a divider. Check if you can still see this periodic pulse then.